# AWS Application Load Balancer Target Group Shows Unhealthy Instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I am facing an issue with my AWS infrastructure where the target group of my load balancer is showing unhealthy instances. This problem started after I migrated from manual provisioning to using Terraform for infrastructure as code. I've thoroughly checked my application and containers, and they seem to be functioning correctly. The application returns a 200 status code, and the containers start and drain.

My AWS infrastructure includes:

- An Application Load Balancer
- An ECS Cluster with Fargate tasks

When making a request to our Application Load Balancer, we are receiving a 504 error response.

I've been working on comparing our staging environment with an existing manually provisioned one. Here's what I've done so far:

Listener Rules: I reviewed the listener rules for discrepancies.
Timeout Intervals: Adjusted timeout intervals.
Health Checks: Temporarily disabled health checks to troubleshoot.
Initially, I encountered a 143 error, which resulted in killing the container. To address this, I increased the memory allocation. However, now I'm encountering a 503 error, indicating that the load balancer is failing health checks.

I'd appreciate your insights and assistance in resolving the 503 error and ensuring that our staging environment is running smoothly.

Comment: It would be really helpful to see your Terraform code for your ECS cluster/tasks/ALB. Otherwise we just have to make guesses as to what could be wrong. Given that you have compared against a working target group already, I suggest comparing the ECS task's security group, specifically to check if it allows access from the load balancer. And double check all port configuration settings in the ECS task, Service, and Target Group.